# Look up an array of objects for the one having necessary key and return its value

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to check if a variable matches a key in an object array, then save the key's value into a variable?

I kinda know what to do but not sure how to write it :/

```
const securityGroupUsers = [
  {SiteSupport: "aedd8266-4015-42ea-bc1e-1325b7ee111f"},
  {ServiceDesk: "b750295b-2c02-4c6b-b5cc-019b06f01650"},
  {ServiceSupportTeam: "59f8e8ea-36d3-4e8c-aeee-c93823c94fb7"}
]

const variableForChecking = 'ServiceDesk';

// let valueNeeded = "b750295b-2c02-4c6b-b5cc-019b06f01650"

// TODO: Loop through securityGroupUsers to see if valueForChecking matches the key of any of the objects inside the array. If it does, then save the key value into a variable.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing you may do is to use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to look up for an item that has required key, than access necessary property of matching item:

```js
const securityGroupUsers = [
        {SiteSupport: "aedd8266-4015-42ea-bc1e-1325b7ee111f"},
        {ServiceDesk: "b750295b-2c02-4c6b-b5cc-019b06f01650"},
        {ServiceSupportTeam: "59f8e8ea-36d3-4e8c-aeee-c93823c94fb7"}
      ],
      findItemValueByKey = (obj,keyName) => obj.find(item => keyName in item)[keyName]

console.log(findItemValueByKey(securityGroupUsers,'ServiceDesk'))
```

Comment: I think the second solution fits, let me try this thank you!

Comment: @BennKingy : I've simplified that a bit, you should try out updated version